# (Fedora) I have java installed but I get an error when I try to see the version: java: command not found

Tags: java, fedora, javac

I'm new to linux and I uninstalled and installed java because javac was in different versions, now I don't know why I'm getting this error, I installed java SE 16.

I am getting an error every time I run "java --version" [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3XN7.png)

```
yum list installed |grep java:

java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64                         1:1.8.0.292.b10-3.fc34               @updates                                    
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64                1:1.8.0.292.b10-3.fc34               @updates                                    

java-11-openjdk.x86_64                            1:11.0.11.0.9-2.fc34                 @updates                                    

java-11-openjdk-devel.x86_64                      1:11.0.11.0.9-2.fc34                 @updates                                    

java-11-openjdk-headless.x86_64                   1:11.0.11.0.9-2.fc34                 @updates                                    

java-latest-openjdk.x86_64                        1:16.0.1.0.9-3.rolling.fc34          @updates                                    

java-latest-openjdk-headless.x86_64               1:16.0.1.0.9-3.rolling.fc34          @updates                                    

javapackages-filesystem.noarch                    5.3.0-15.fc34                        @fedora                                     

tzdata-java.noarch                                2021a-1.fc34                         @fedora
```

Comment: Fedora 34: I installed the same, in this order → java-latest, java-1.8.0, java-11. .... `ls /etc/alternatives/java` replies `java`. ... ... `java --version` replies openjdk version "11.0.11". ..... May be you have a broken link in /etc/alternatives/? ... Please check with `# alternatives --config java` → I get three choices ... The same for `javac`